# How to get link to be clickable on the full height of the navigation menu

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, navbar, anchor

I have created a nav bar that is 40px high. I want the link to be clickable on the full size of the menu - not just the word 'home', 'about', etc.

Any advice?

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="nav">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
       <li><a href="Services.html">Services Information</a></li>
       <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
}       
#nav ul {
        background-color: black;
        float: right;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
}               
#nav ul li {
        color: #fff;
        float: left;
        padding: 20px;
}
#nav ul li a {
        color:#fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        line-height: 40px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 26px;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height:100%;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
        color: #75b2de;
        background-color: #222;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
        color: #75b2de;
        background-color: #222;
}
```

Fiddle is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/yesdeer/6v2Ljnod/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take away padding of li element and add padding to a - than should do the trick. Then you just need to think abut parameters of those paddings so it would look ok.

```
#nav ul li {
    /* padding: 20px; */
}

#nav ul li a{
    padding: 20px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Anrzej Answer you can work around with height and line height as well.

```
#nav ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 80px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 26px;
    display: block;
    /* width: 100%; */
    height: 80px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```